# Having problems with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, web

Recently my Chrome (version 81) started to have 'Aw, Snap!' errors that mention STATUS_BREAKPOINT in every page, as well as the settings page, for some reason.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: ok, this also happens on the chrome settings for some reason

Comment: Are you referring to ['Aw, Snap' crashes](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/17555930?hl=en)? What Chrome version do you have?

Comment: @Primoz yes, suddently the page goes to the error page, i have chrome 81

Comment: As the issue is not programming-related, the questions is better suited for the [Power User](https://superuser.com/) site. Try the suggestions in the linked thread though.